# How to fix error A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, samesite

I use google tag manager on my website with this method -> https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart (using iframe)

Now i have this warning on the console when i access to my website :

*"A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests ...."*

After my research i discover that this warning can't be fixed on my side but only on the google side.
But i still have the warning despite the release of Chrome v80 is on.

Am i alone to have this problem ? do you know how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are associated with `google.com`, so it's not something that you need to change. We are working on cleaning up some of the false positives that appear in the log, however some of these cookies are set without a `SameSite` attribute for compatibility reasons with older browsers.

You can see https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/ for more context.